# CSS/JS src without schema does not work with CSP

Tags: javascript, css, content-security-policy

While I am loading JS/CSS with `src="//localhost/something"`

It cannot pass the CSP as following

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' localhost`

It block the JS/CSS with warning

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("default-src http://localhost http://localhost"). Source: @import 
url("//localhost/something"...`

Is it possible to keep using src without schema to auto handle http/https when using CSP ?

Comment: I believe it should by default allow both http and https schemes unless you specifically designate the https scheme `default-src 'self' https://localhost`

Comment: Sorry guys, finally found that it is due to the unsafe-inline part of script-src